# how to have wait for last task and results for each in coroutine on Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I have two tasks. Both load data to view model (eg. `LoadDataList1UseCase` and `LoadDataList2UseCase`).
When new fragment is started then data should be loaded in view model. But when any of load process finish then data fetched by it should be loaded to view (recycler view) but only when both finish then progress bar should be hidden.

I figure out some like below but doesn't work. What I miss? How look like correct approach?

```
class LoadDataList1UseCase {
   operator fun invoke() = flow { 
      delay(3_000)
      emit("a")
   }
}
class LoadDataList2UseCase {
   operator fun invoke() = flow { emit("b")}
}

//------------ method in view model:
suspend fun loadData() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
   loadDataList1
      .onEatch { /*update screan*/}
   loadDataList2
      .onEatch { /*update screan*/}
}
```

and run it in runBlocking

I'm totally newbie in coroutine. In rx, I would be try mix combinedLatest and doOnComplite

Answer (score 0):

You do it in a similar way to RxJava, it is even named [combine()](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) as well:

```kotlin
loadDataList1
    .combine(loadDataList2, ::Pair)
    .collect { (first, second) ->
        /*update screen*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use [`merge`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/merge.html) function to merge flows concurrently. In this case `collect` action lambda will be invoked when data is emitted in either of flows. In your [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel) class:

  ```
  class MyViewModel(...) : ViewModel() {

      fun loadData() = viewModelScope.launch {
        merge(loadDataList1(), loadDataList2())
            .collect {
                // update UI (RecyclerView)
            }
        // both flows are finished, hide progress bar here
      }
  }
  ```
- There is also [`combine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) function (not extension function) that accepts `Flow`s to combine and `transform` block, it defined like the following:

  fun <T1, T2, R> combine(flow: Flow, flow2: Flow, transform: suspend (T1, T2) -> R): Flow

  You can use it in your [`ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModel) class:

  ```
  class MyViewModel(...) : ViewModel() {
    init {
        combine(
            loadDataList1(),
            loadDataList2()
        ) { result1, result2 ->
            // use result1 and result2
            // hide progress
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope) // Terminal flow operator that launches the collection of the given flow in the scope. It is a shorthand for scope.launch { flow.collect() }.
    }
  }
  ```

  The above approach combines `Flow`s and invokes `transform` with `result1` and `result2` params only when both are available.